# com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/common/internal/zzq.class

Tags: ionic3

I am new in ionic.I am currently working on an ionic 3 app.I am working on push notification in my app but after installing the push plugin and writing the code ,when i run my app this error occurs. I tried many solutions from stack overflow but non of them worked for me.
Please help me.

This is my build.gradle dependency block

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES START
    debugCompile(project(path: "CordovaLib", configuration: "debug"))
    releaseCompile(project(path: "CordovaLib", configuration: "release"))
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.0.4"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.0.4"
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1+"
    compile "com.android.support:support-v13:26.+"
    compile "me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.17@aar"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.6.2"
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES END
}
```

Comment: which push plugin? Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: I am using ionic native phonegap-plugin-push.

Comment: This is the version of the plugin:   <plugin name="phonegap-plugin-push" spec="^2.1.3">
        <variable name="SENDER_ID" value="xxxxx" />
        <variable name="FCM_VERSION" value="11.6.2" />
    </plugin>